# Reset game loop / restart game java swing

Tags: java, swing, game-loop

I am working on a Java Snake Game. Most of the basic functionality is done ubt I am trying to add a restart function that will be triggered when you press ENTER when the game over. All logics semms to work, the snake resets to start position, apple gets new random position etc. But for some reason my JPanels won't repaint. Could you guys take a look and see if you can figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I've made a snapshot out of my code with the game loop, reset function etc. Just let me know if you need more.

```
/*
     * Main class, game loop, keyListener etc
     */

    /*
     * Here is my run method with game loop when gameOver, snake will no longer
     * update.
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // game loop
        while (running) {
            if (!gameOver) {                
                update();
            }

            MainFrame.paint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(60);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

/*
 * KeyListener, when ENTER is pressed call resetGame() method.
 */
if(key.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && gameOver) {
    resetGame();
}


    /*
     * resetGame method where I reset variables, create new default snake, 
     * clear JPanels etc.
     */
    public void resetGame() {
        score = 0;
        snake.clear(); // clear arraylist

        // .removAll() on both JPanels
        MainFrame.clear();

        // fields
        gameOver = false;
        newGame = true;

        direction = Direction.RIGHT;

        // create default snake
        snake = new ArrayList<Point>();
        size = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            snake.add(new Point((size - i - 1) * MainFrame.getTileSize(), 0));
        }
        System.out.println(snake);

        // create apple and set to random location
        apple = randomApple();
    }

    /*
     * MainFrame extends JFrame  
     * methods for repainting and clearing JPanels
     */

    public static void paint() {

        gamePanel.repaint();
        sideHud.repaint();
    }

    public static void clear() {
        gamePanel.removeAll();
        sideHud.removeAll();

        paint();
    }
```

My JPanels are pretty basic. I just paint everything in the paintComponent method with Graphics2D object.

This is my most recent solution (which didn't work). I have also tried, leaving the game loop and then calling on run() again in the resetGame() method, I tried creating a new Main object when ENTER is pressed, but none of them worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `If()` a method you've declared? Because the Java keyword `if` is case-sensitive.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I added that if-statement here, just to clarify. But I accidently typed uppercase i.

Comment: `I have also tried...` - well you are doing something wrong. There is no way we can tell you what the problem is based on the code provided. I would suggest you need a simple method like: playGame(). This method can be invoked the first time you play and when you want to start another game. This method will be responsible to setting the properties of the game and then starting the Thead to play the game. So variables like "running" and "gameOver" would need to be reset in addition to the position of the snake and apple.

Comment: Too incomplete code to answer... What MainFrame.paint() does? clear()? etc. Where are Panels created/recreated, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well first check if the game is over via an if so create a Boolean that is set to true when the game is over. When that Boolean becomes true create a method that is called that resets all the variables in your game method and any other variables related to the game. Then call the game method (whatever triggers your game to work). Voila your game has reset hope that helped.